# タブコントロール内のチェックBOXにチェックを入れ、タブページを切り替えるとチェックが外れてしまう

Tags: wpf

WPFにて、画面の中にタブを動的に作り、その各タブページの中には、チェックBOXを生成しています。
生成した画面を起動し、チェックBOXにチェックを入れたタブページを切り替えたのち、元のタブページに戻るとチェックBOXのチェックが外れてしまいます。
どうすればチェックを保持できるのか、ご教示お願い致します。

チェックBOXのCheckedイベント処理では、IsCheckedにtrueを設定してみましたが、チェックは保持されませんでした。

＜XAML抜粋＞

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl" Margin="50,15,0,15">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" FontFamily="MS Gothic"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                ～～～中略～～～
                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding TabCk}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Checked="Checked" Unchecked="UnChecked" HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:DataContext="{Binding CheckKey}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="35,0,0,5"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

＜ソースコード抜粋＞

```
/// <summary>
/// タブとチェックBOXを作成する
/// </summary>
public void MakeTab()
{   // タブとチェックBOXの作成処理
    var source = Enumerable.Range(1, TabCnt).Select(j => new CustomTabItem {
                        Header   = "Tab" + j,
                        CheckKey = "Check" + j 
                        }); 
    this.TabControl.ItemsSource = source;   // タブとチェックBOX生成
}

/// <summary>
/// チェックイベント
/// </summary>
private void Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   // チェックイベント処理
    System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox chkObj = (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)sender;
    chkObj.IsChecked = true;                                                                        
}
```

Comment: ピンポイントで1つだけのチェックボックス関連ソースを提示されても問題を再現・調査出来ないのでは？ 複数のタブとチェックボックスを表示して確認出来る程度のソースを提示するか、そうしたリポジトリを用意して紹介リンクを提示してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
質問文章の見直し、XAML、コードビハインドの添付内容見直しを行いました。ご確認いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 済みません、以前の質問もそうですが今提示されているソースや情報だけで問題を再現・調査できるでしょうか？ WPFの知識・経験が豊富な人なら色々と補完して出来るのかもしれませんが、それでも難しいのでは？ 例えば記事を長大にしたくないのであれば、プロジェクト一式を外部のリポジトリ等に用意して紹介リンクを貼るとか、既存のWPFサンプルを紹介してこの部分を追加すれば良いといった記述にした方が、助言や回答を得られる可能性が高くなると思うのですが。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
見直しをするにあたり、一度質問を削除して内容を見直したいと思います。

Comment: もしかしたらこんな記事が参考になるかもしれませんね。[How to save the check box state in WPF?](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/wdfcbu/how_to_save_the_check_box_state_in_wpf/), [WPFのデータバインディングとは？C#によるデータの操作方法](https://www.fenet.jp/dotnet/column/language/4973/), [WPF　CheckBox.IsCheckedを双方向バインディングする方法](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/281d6250-8536-43dd-b3e9-679e5de607fd/), [WPF checkbox IsChecked two way binding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48860867/9014308), [WPF CheckBox TwoWay Binding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16094679/9014308)